# Overloading Generates Error Even Though Signatures Are Different

Tags: .net, vb.net, overloading

Using vb.net I have this function:

```
 Public Overloads Function GetCountValues(ByVal CampaignIDValue As String,
                                             ByVal AgentValue As String,
                                             ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Integer
```

I overload because we are doing the same thing with this function just without the AgentValue.

```
Public Overloads Function GetCountValues(ByVal CampaignIDValue As String, ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Integer
```

But the compiler insists the signature is the same even though they are not. If I change the second CampaignIDValue to "As Object" it is fine until you try to actually use it. There has got to be something I am missing to make this work. If you can help I would appreciate it.

The others with no problem:(thanks for your patience HardCode).

```
Public Overloads Function GetCountValues(ByVal AgentValue As String,
                                             ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Integer
```

```
Public Overloads Function GetCountValues(ByVal CampaignIDValue As String,
                                             ByVal AgentValue As String,
                                             ByVal LCDATEValue As Date,
                                             ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Integer
```

this one also generates an error if change object back to string

```
Public Overloads Function GetCountValues(ByVal CampaignIDValue As Object,
                                             ByVal LCDATEValue As Date,
                                             ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Integer
```

The whole class. Copy and paste into a vb.net class and I THINk it will give you the same error:

```
Public Class clsExample

    ''' <summary>
    ''' CampaignID and Agent Driven Count Values
    ''' </summary>
    Public Overloads Function GetCountValues(ByVal CampaignIDValue As String,
                                             ByVal AgentValue As String,
                                             ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Integer
        Dim x = From p In myTable.AsEnumerable
                Where LTrim(RTrim(p.CAMPAIGNID)).ToLower =
                    LTrim(RTrim(CampaignIDValue)).ToLower _
                    And LTrim(RTrim(p.AGENT)).ToLower = LTrim(RTrim(AgentValue)).ToLower _
                    And p.TERMCD.Contains(SearchTerm) 'Order By p.AGENT
                Group p By p.CAMPAIGNID, p.AGENT Into Group
                Select New With {.CAMPAIGNID = CAMPAIGNID, .Agent = AGENT, .FunctionValue = Group.Count()}
        If x.Any = True Then
            Return x.ElementAt(0).FunctionValue
        Else
            Return 0
            ' Dim NewEntry = New With {.CAMPAIGNID = CampaignIDValue, .Agent = AgentValue, .FunctionValue = 0}
            'x = NewEntry
            ' Dim Copy = x.Append(NewEntry)
            'Return Copy

        End If
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' CampaignID Driven Count Values
    ''' </summary>
    Public Overloads Function GetCountValues(ByVal CampaignIDValue As String, ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Integer
        Dim x = From p In myTable.AsEnumerable
                Where LTrim(RTrim(p.CAMPAIGNID)).ToLower =
                    LTrim(RTrim(CampaignIDValue)).ToLower _
                    And p.TERMCD.Contains(SearchTerm) 'Order By p.AGENT
                Group p By p.CAMPAIGNID Into Group
                Select New With {.CAMPAIGNID = CAMPAIGNID, .FunctionValue = Group.Count()}
        If x.Any = True Then
            Return x.ElementAt(0).FunctionValue
        Else
            Return 0
            ' Dim NewEntry = New With {.CAMPAIGNID = CampaignIDValue, .Agent = AgentValue, .FunctionValue = 0}
            'x = NewEntry
            ' Dim Copy = x.Append(NewEntry)
            'Return Copy

        End If
    End Function


    'Public Overloads Function GetCountValues(ByVal CampaignIDValue As String,
    '                                         ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Integer
    '    Dim x = From p In myTable.AsEnumerable
    '            Where LTrim(RTrim(p.CAMPAIGNID)).ToLower =
    '                LTrim(RTrim(CampaignIDValue)).ToLower _
    '                And p.TERMCD.Contains(SearchTerm)
    '            Group p By p.CAMPAIGNID Into Group
    '            Select New With {.CAMPAIGNID = CAMPAIGNID, .FunctionValue = Group.Count()}
    '    If x.Any = True Then
    '        Return x.ElementAt(0).FunctionValue
    '    Else
    '        Return 0
    '        ' Dim NewEntry = New With {.CAMPAIGNID = CampaignIDValue, .Agent = AgentValue, .FunctionValue = 0}
    '        'x = NewEntry
    '        ' Dim Copy = x.Append(NewEntry)
    '        'Return Copy

    '    End If
    'End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Agent Driven Count Values
    ''' </summary>
    Public Overloads Function GetCountValues(ByVal AgentValue As String,
                                             ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Integer
        Dim x = From p In myTable.AsEnumerable
                Where LTrim(RTrim(p.AGENT)).ToLower =
                    LTrim(RTrim(AgentValue)).ToLower _
                    And p.TERMCD.Contains(SearchTerm)
                Group p By p.AGENT Into Group
                Select New With {.Agent = AgentValue, .FunctionValue = Group.Count()}
        If x.Any = True Then
            Return x.ElementAt(0).FunctionValue
        Else
            Return 0
            ' Dim NewEntry = New With {.CAMPAIGNID = CampaignIDValue, .Agent = AgentValue, .FunctionValue = 0}
            'x = NewEntry
            ' Dim Copy = x.Append(NewEntry)
            'Return Copy

        End If
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' LCDate, CampaignID and Agent Driven Count Values
    ''' </summary>
    Public Overloads Function GetCountValues(ByVal CampaignIDValue As String,
                                             ByVal AgentValue As String,
                                             ByVal LCDATEValue As Date,
                                             ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Integer
        Dim x = From p In myTable.AsEnumerable
                Where LTrim(RTrim(p.CAMPAIGNID)).ToLower =
                    LTrim(RTrim(CampaignIDValue)).ToLower _
                    And LTrim(RTrim(p.AGENT)).ToLower = LTrim(RTrim(AgentValue)).ToLower _
                    And p.TERMCD.Contains(SearchTerm) 'Order By p.AGENT
                Group p By p.LCDATE, p.CAMPAIGNID, p.AGENT Into Group
                Select New With {.LCDATE = LCDATEValue, .CAMPAIGNID = CAMPAIGNID, .Agent = AGENT, .FunctionValue = Group.Count()}
        If x.Any = True Then
            Return x.ElementAt(0).FunctionValue
        Else
            Return 0
            ' Dim NewEntry = New With {.CAMPAIGNID = CampaignIDValue, .Agent = AgentValue, .FunctionValue = 0}
            'x = NewEntry
            ' Dim Copy = x.Append(NewEntry)
            'Return Copy

        End If
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' LCDate and CampaignID Driven Count Values
    ''' </summary>
    Public Overloads Function GetCountValues(ByVal CampaignIDValue As Object,
                                             ByVal LCDATEValue As Date,
                                             ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Integer
        Dim x = From p In myTable.AsEnumerable
                Where LTrim(RTrim(p.CAMPAIGNID)).ToLower =
                    LTrim(RTrim(CampaignIDValue)).ToLower _
                    And p.TERMCD.Contains(SearchTerm) 'Order By p.AGENT
                Group p By p.LCDATE, p.CAMPAIGNID Into Group
                Select New With {.LCDATE = LCDATEValue, .CAMPAIGNID = CAMPAIGNID, .FunctionValue = Group.Count()}
        If x.Any = True Then
            Return x.ElementAt(0).FunctionValue
        Else
            Return 0
            ' Dim NewEntry = New With {.CAMPAIGNID = CampaignIDValue, .Agent = AgentValue, .FunctionValue = 0}
            'x = NewEntry
            ' Dim Copy = x.Append(NewEntry)
            'Return Copy

        End If
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' LCDate and Agent Driven Count Values
    ''' </summary>
    Public Overloads Function GetCountValues(ByVal AgentValue As String,
                                             ByVal LCDATEValue As Date,
                                             ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Integer
        Dim x = From p In myTable.AsEnumerable
                Where LTrim(RTrim(p.AGENT)).ToLower =
                    LTrim(RTrim(AgentValue)).ToLower _
                    And p.TERMCD.Contains(SearchTerm) 'Order By p.AGENT
                Group p By p.LCDATE, p.AGENT Into Group
                Select New With {.LCDATE = LCDATEValue, .Agent = AgentValue, .FunctionValue = Group.Count()}
        If x.Any = True Then
            Return x.ElementAt(0).FunctionValue
        Else
            Return 0
            ' Dim NewEntry = New With {.CAMPAIGNID = CampaignIDValue, .Agent = AgentValue, .FunctionValue = 0}
            'x = NewEntry
            ' Dim Copy = x.Append(NewEntry)
            'Return Copy

        End If
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' LCDate Driven Count Values
    ''' </summary>
    Public Overloads Function GetCountValues(ByVal LCDATEValue As Date,
                                             ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Integer
        Dim x = From p In myTable.AsEnumerable
                Where p.LCDATE =
                    LCDATEValue _
                    And p.TERMCD.Contains(SearchTerm) 'Order By p.AGENT
                Group p By p.LCDATE Into Group
                Select New With {.LCDATE = LCDATEValue, .FunctionValue = Group.Count()}
        If x.Any = True Then
            Return x.ElementAt(0).FunctionValue
        Else
            Return 0
            ' Dim NewEntry = New With {.CAMPAIGNID = CampaignIDValue, .Agent = AgentValue, .FunctionValue = 0}
            'x = NewEntry
            ' Dim Copy = x.Append(NewEntry)
            'Return Copy

        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: I suspect it would be easier for us to help you if you could provide a [mcve]. You may well find that in providing that example, you work out the problem.

Comment: Is it ok to paste that under your comment?

Comment: No, you should edit your question. I see you've already done so, but this really isn't *minimal* at all. We don't need any XML comments, or method implementations beyond returning a constant - just a minimal example showing the overload failure.

Comment: question is edited. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: It's still 190 lines of code. After removing the comments and implementation, I've got it down to 41 lines of code. That's what I'm looking for - a *minimal* example.

Answer (score 2):

**The names of the parameter variables do not matter to the signature!**

We need to be able to call functions like this:

```
result = GetCountValues("string1", "string2")
```

If you have two overloads of a function which match this and differ only by the names of the arguments, there's no way to know which one you mean. Therefore, for the class in the question, these two methods conflict with each other:

```
Public Overloads Function GetCountValues(ByVal CampaignIDValue As String,
                                         ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Integer

Public Overloads Function GetCountValues(ByVal AgentValue As String,
                                         ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Integer
```

Possibly others, too. I stopped looking at that point.

Comment: what I did was add ", Optional ByVal PlaceHolderObject As Object = Nothing" and everything was fine. Thanks for your time this morning.

Comment: @KJM: Rather than adding a pointless additional parameter, I'd rename the method - when you're reading the calling code, I'm sure you'll want to know whether you're trying to count by agent or campaign ID - so put that in the name.

Comment: Your right and it didn't work anyway. It still wanted to find the first function. Thanks much for your help...

Answer (score 0):

If these are the only two function signatures in the system for `GetCountValues`, and you're not overloading a third function that already exists by that name in a parent Class, just simply declare the functions this way:

```
Public Function GetCountValues(ByVal CampaignIDValue As String, ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Integer

    Return GetCountValues(CampaignIDValue, SearchTerm, String.Empty)

End Function

Public Function GetCountValues(ByVal CampaignIDValue As String,
                               ByVal SearchTerm As String,
                               ByVal AgentValue As String) As Integer

    ' The actual code.

End Function
```

Get into the habit of putting the parameters in the same order, too.

### EDIT:

As I can see in your edited question (and as Joel Coehoorn already pointed out), you have functions with the same signature (e.g. two parameters of type String).

Comment: I have 5 different overloads of this function. None of them give me a problem except those involving CampaignIDValue. Trying out your idea now.

Comment: Well then, can you edit your question to include all five? The missing three might be telling. Also, are they all in the same class/module?

Comment: Also, I'd point out the obvious that variable names do NOT determine function signature, rather the data types do. `Foo(x As String, y As String)` is the same function signature as `Foo(name As String, address As String)`.

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity I am trying to edit the question. I am new here so I am struggling with it a bit.